# How to keep an ArrayList when changing activities in Android?

Tags: java, android

**This is my activity to send data to TambahDataEstimasi:**

```
private void tambahdataEstimasi(String string) {

     dialogCustom = new AlertDialog.Builder(PartActivity.this);
     dialogCustom.setCancelable(true);
     dialogCustom.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_file);
     dialogCustom.setTitle("Tambah Data Estimasi");
     dialogCustom.setMessage("Apakah Anda Ingin Menambahkan Data : \n" + string + " Ke Daftar Estimasi?");
     dialogCustom.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(PartActivity.this, TambahEstimasi.class);
             intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("dataestimasi", adapter.checkedPart);
             startActivity(intent);

         }
     });

     dialogCustom.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             dialog.dismiss();
             adapter.checkedPart.clear();
         }
     });

     dialogCustom.show();

}
```

**This is my TambahDataEstimasi to get data from the previous activity:**

```
public class TambahEstimasi extends AppCompatActivity {


ArrayList<ModelPart> listEstimasi = new ArrayList<>();
ModelPart part ;

ArrayList<ModelPart> estimasiPart = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tambah_estimasi);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardView_estimasi);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    listEstimasi =  intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("dataestimasi");

    System.out.println("data Intent : " + listEstimasi.size());

    for (int i=0; i<listEstimasi.size(); i++) {

        part = listEstimasi.get(i);
        String nomor = part.getNomorPart().toString();

        System.out.println("Isi data Intent : " + nomor);
    }
```

When I go back to the previous activity, my ArrayList data in TambahDataEstimasi is lost. What should I do to keep the ArrayList data?

Comment: post code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: i have already edited

Answer (score 0):

When you go back to you previous activity by pressing a back button or by calling finish, the activity gets destroyed, the data is no longer preserved.. If you want to preserve yoir data,. there are many techniques yoi can use.

Answer (score 0):

Use onSaveInstanceState method in your activity to save the state

```java
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArray(array,"key");
}
```

Once you are coming back to the activity, restore the state onRestoreInstanceState method

```java
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray("key");
}
```

The array must contain items that implement Parcelable interface. You can choose to implement the interface in your ModelPart class or you can use a third party library called Parceler https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

Comment: i got eror, where may i put two methods?

Comment: Post the error, you should put the methods in the first activity (the one within you want save the data)

Comment: why i cant post image here?

Comment: You should share a repository in order to look to your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sharedPreferences` for this purpose.

```
public <T> void putList(String key, List<T> list) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, gson.toJson(list));
        editor.apply();
    }

    public <T> List<T> getList(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
        Type typeOfT = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, clazz).getType();
        return gson.fromJson(getString(key, null), typeOfT);
    }
```

These above funtions need to be put in a PrefManager Class like this:

```
    public class PrefManager {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private Gson gson;

    public PrefManager(Context context, Gson gson) {
        this.sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.gson = gson;
    } 

    ...

    public <T> void putList(String key, List<T> list) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, gson.toJson(list));
        editor.apply();
    }

    public <T> List<T> getList(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
        Type typeOfT = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, clazz).getType();
        return gson.fromJson(getString(key, null), typeOfT);
    }
}
```

Then call when you want to set the list:

```
prefManager.putList(prefManager.Key.USER_LIST, userList);
```

Then when you want to retreive it:

```
List<User> userList = prerManager.getList(PrefManager.Key.USER_LIST, User.class);
```

Refer from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)